# Show text outside itemize step by step

Tags: beamer, itemize

I know how to show lists step by step when I create presentations with beamer, but how can I show simple text step by step without itemizing it?

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    <1-> First\\
    <2-> Second:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<3-> Third
        \item<4-> Fourth
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I want to show to paragraphs of text following with a list. How can I reveal the paragraphs step by step? My example is working for the list, but does not work for plain text.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Could you provide some more explicit details? For example, on slide ONE I want "X", on slide TWO I want "X Y", on slide THREE I want "X y Z", ...?

Comment: You could use 'only' or visible' like this: '\frame{% \visible<1> First \\ \visible<2->second \\ \only<3> third}'

Comment: The (currently) accepted answer by @samcarter might work, but for certain cases @bobyandbob or @Zarco's method (\visible or \uncover respectively) is slightly better. They work better  with `\item<>` than `\pause` does, and allow for more flexibility.

Comment: You could always change your accepted answer, if you get an better answer (for example of Zarko). - Should i write an answer of my comment?

Comment: @Bobyandbob thanks, I updated the correct answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand you correctly than you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Uncovered paragraphs}
\uncover<1->{
This is the first paragraph.
            } 
\bigskip

\uncover<2->{
The second paragraph with long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long text in two lines.
            }
\bigskip

\uncover<3->{
The third paragraph.
            }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for `\pause`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    First\pause

    Second:
    \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
        \item Third
        \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```